# CSS "inherit" not working as expected with focus state

Tags: html, css

Apparently I need some education on how the `inherit` value works in CSS.  I'm trying to use it with an element using the `:focus` selector to make sure that, on focus, the border color doesn't change.  I'm doing this because I want to override Bootstrap's default behavior which creates a blue "glow" around focused input elements on forms.

But oddly, when I set `border-color:inherit` under `input:focus`, the border just goes black on focus.  [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/e4mzfo3v/1/)'s a jsfiddle demonstrating this.  The first `input` has an explicit color under `focus` and that works fine.  The Second `input` uses `inherit` just goes to black on focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working as expected, you're missunderstanding what the `inherit` keyword actually does.

It takes the computed value of the property of the **parent** element, `input`  isn't the parent of `input:focus`. If you were to put your `input`  in a `div`, and specify a border-color for that `div`, then the `inherit`  would mean the color of the input's border would be the one of the `div`'s border .

Exemple: https://jsfiddle.net/e4mzfo3v/1/

Comment: While the other answers are also helpful, I picked yours because it explains the exact conceptual issue that I had.  It thought a `focus` element was treated like a child of the original element.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Inherit will retrieve the computed value from the immediate parent (and that parent will only receive an inherited value if it's explicitly defined).  None is found, so it defaults to black.  If you set a parent value to red, it will work..

**Example of No Outline -** `#input2:focus { outline: 0; }`

Comment: ok, I thought `:focus` was treated like a child of the element.  Is there a CSS setting to just "keep value from unfocused state"?

Comment: If you are looking to keep the red border red; just don't include the focus in your CSS.  If you don't want the blue outline that exists on the outside of the box, you would do `outline: 0;` as part of your :focus definition.

Comment: Inherit does not climb parent to parent to parent. It only takes the computed value of the property from the parent.

Comment: @jhansen, I understand that I could just remove the focus attribute, but the jsfiddle I provide is just a trivial example.  I as I said in my question, I'm trying to override Bootstrap's `focus` behavior for a form element, hence the "keep property the same" idea for focus.  But I'm getting the sense that's just not possible?

Comment: Could you show a more specific example? Based on my current understanding, im thinking you would either create a "single tier" more specific definition, or create the same definition and load your css after bootstraps

Answer (score -2):

The `inherit` value tells the element to use the value from the parent element. Your inputs don't have parents, therefore, nothing to reference to...

Instead, set the property with the `!important` flag to keep it from being overridden:

[**Updated JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/e4mzfo3v/4/)

```
#input2 {
    border-color:red !important;
    border-width:10px;
}
```

Comment: Using `!important` should be avoided as much as possible. Simply using `#input2, #input2:focus { border-color: red; }` would do the trick

Comment: @StephanMuller - I don't know if you are the downvoter, but I disagree... When used wisely, `!important` may be useful. Saying it *should not* is not quite an argument.

Comment: A self written post with no external sources is not really an argument.

Comment: @StephanMuller - But that's ok... I'm sure that the other 111 (so far) voters may have had a good reason to agree with you...

Comment: You have a point though. That answer still gets activity, I should add some external sources just to be more complete.